# Apache2 Setup Ubuntu

Tags: http, ubuntu, apache2

I'm having problems with setting up my apache2 server in Ubuntu.

I did a sudo apt-get install and it installed normally. I was able to see that the site was working when accessing localhost.

Then I'm not sure what happened, but I am no longer able to see the "It works!" website. When I try to restart apache2, it returns this:

```
Syntax error on line 17 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
AddHandler requires at least two arguments, a handler name followed by one or more file extensions
Action 'configtest' failed. 
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

Any ideas?

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.py

    AddHandler mod_python.py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
    PythonDebug On
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Can you give us your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem on your config file. Try changing the line 14 by :

```
AddHandler mod_python .py
```